# What do you use for personal note-taking at work?

Tags: management, meetings, projects

I want to transition away from using my handwritten notebook to maintain personal note-taking and record keeping for projects, meetings, and just my progress notes/thoughts on things.

Main problems that I want to work around / solve

- Centralised / cloud store and viewable on my phone and Win PCs.
- Searchable by date, topic/title, contents, note categories
- Handle attachments and screenshots
- Support freehand drawing

In the past, I used to maintain txt files for each meeting or project, that I would open in Notepad++ or something similar. it worked ok for a while, and was handly when I was also using it for coding (which I don't do in my current role).

I was put onto OneNote by local IT support, but I just can't manage to adopt it completely. It doesn't seem to click for me. I've tried the desktop app and the web app. It does solve the problems stated above... I just can't manage to stick with it for a long time.

My current workflow has come down to sending emails to myself. Is there a better solution or system out there that you're using?

Comment: Questions like this are usually out of scope for stack exchange. As they are opinion related.

But look into Notion or apps like it. It sounds like that is what you need.

Comment: Would this be better to ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is very opinion and preference based. As a programmer, I've tried various note-taking apps but in the end, it seems like plain text files still work the best for me, even for non programming-related digital notes. But clearly this would only work if your notes are mostly text based, and if you're already comfortable working with plain text files, text editors, grep, etc.

Comment: While I'm typically not a fan of MS Office, I thought OneNote is one of the better ones. I particularly the natural organization into books, sections and pages which gave way to stay organized. Your mileage may vary

Comment: You should still search at the Software recommendation stack as mentioned in comments and @Sourav's answer. But as a quick suggestion, give ___Notability___ a try. Its not free, but its very robust and has most all of the features you're looking for. Links with Google Drive, organization into any categories you'd like, easy to cut and paste screenshots, able to draw freehand. Only thing I'm not sure of is if the notes can be edited on a PC, but if you have a tablet/phone that you're using to take them, give it a try :)

Answer (score 3):

While in many cases you are free to choose any application you'd like, in some cases, you are restricted by the IT policy in your workplace about using any software / service / storage which stores corporate / project related data / information.

The best solution: check with your IT team first about whether you're allowed to use *any* software as you like, and ask them for alternates. In case there is a restriction, your choices may be limited and you are bound to use any of them (whether you like it or not).

However, if you get a free hand, you can try searching / asking in [Software recommendation Stack](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).